# IndexError: string index out of range. While-Loop goes one round too much

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I know there are other problems similar to this but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I've implemented some "tracking"-code to understand where it goes wrong. The problem is obviously the same for other parts of the code as well depending on what is run through the `tokenize` function. I know the problem exists because of the `end += 1` in the while-loops  and doesn't stop/continue correctly. After the last letter/number/symbol is read it should add it to `words` but instead it tries to go one further step and creates this error. Tried numerous if's and tries things but my coding is to weak to solve it properly. Any other comments of the code in general is much appreciated as well. I had a draft that was working earlier but I accidentally deleted that draft when I was supposed to polish it and move it to another document...

```
def tokenize(lines):
words = []
for line in lines:
    print("new line")
    start = 0
    
    while start-1 < len(line):
        print(start)
        print("start")
        while line[start].isspace() == True:
            print("remove space")
            start += 1
        end = start
        while line[end].isspace() == True:
            print("remove space")
            end += 1
        if line[end].isalpha() == True:
            while line[end].isalpha() == True:
                print("letter")
                end += 1
        elif line[end].isdigit() == True:
            while line[end].isdigit() == True:
                print("number")
                end += 1
        else:
            print("symbol")
            end += 1
        words.append(line[start:end].lower())
        print(line[start:end] + " - adds to words")
        start = end
        print(len(line))
        print(words)
return words
```

`tokenize(["   all .. 12 foas d 12 9"])`

Comment: I think this entire function be replaced with `[word for line in lines for word in line.lower().strip().split()]`

Comment: Is this an attempt to write a simple parser?

Comment: @j1-lee this is the first part of a program which is supposed to tokenize strings and will later on count how often each word appears.

@0x5453 strip() is not doing the work I want to be done. With strip() symbols would be attached to words. E. g. `["Hello, how are you doing?"]` Would get the output `["Hello,", "how", "are", "you", "doing?"]` which won't work with the code following this function.

@line-o I guess you could call it a simple parser, or at least a part of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you have to check your indexing bounds in every part of the code where indexing variables might have changed. This includes both `start` and `end` variables as they are independently incremented within your code.

I also cut out areas of your code which were unnecessary and considered mainly *duplicate code* and untidy logic, which you have to avoid in every program you write. This also makes it easier to debug, maintain, and understand your program. Always make sure your logic gets as straightforward as possible before you start writing any code.

```
def tokenize(lines):
    words = []
   
    for line in lines:
        print("new line")
        start = 0
        
        # start, as an index, is allowed in the range [0, len(line) - 1]
        # so use either *start < len(line)* or *start <= len(line) - 1* as they are equivalent
        while start < len(line):
            print(start)
            print("start")
            # going forward, watch not to overstep again
            while start < len(line) and line[start].isspace():
                print("remove space")
                start += 1
            end = start
            # whatever variable you use as an index, you have to make sure
            # it will be within bounds; as you go forward to capture 
            # non-space symbols, you should also stop before the string finishes.
            while end < len(line) and not line[end].isspace():
                if line[end].isalpha():
                    print("letter")
                elif line[end].isdigit():
                    print("number")
                else:
                    print("symbol")
                end += 1
            words.append(line[start:end].lower())
            print(line[start:end] + " - adds to words")
            start = end
            print(len(line))
            print(words)
```

UPDATE:

It seems the OP is trying to keep the non-alphanumeric symbols as separate tokens. I suggest not doing this in a single passing. You can first split the normal way and then go over each word again to split by symbols (and retain symbols). This will keep your code simpler and easier to read. I'm going to use regex split for the second step:

```
import re

greeting = "Hey, how are you doing?"
# get rid of spaces
tokens = greeting.split()
result = []
for w in tokens:
    # '[^\d\w]' will match symbol characters (non-digit and non-alpha)
    # parentheses will capture the delimiters (the symbols) as tokens in the final list
    for x in re.split("([^\d\w]+)", w):
        if x:
            result.append(x)
print(result)

##### or use list comprehension to achieve this in a single line
result = [x for w in greeting.split() for x in re.split("([^\d\w]+)", w) if x != ""] 
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such great feedback, I will think of this going forward.

Comment: @Roslund You're welcome. I thought this was a programming exercise, that's why I tried to make it work for you. If all you need is more refined splitting, you can use [regex split](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+split+python)

Comment: After trying the code further is does not do what it is supposed to do. I need to separate commas and punctuation from the words. E. g. the input `['He is in the room, she said.']` should get the output `['he', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'room', ',', 'she', 'said', '.']` and not `['he', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'room,', 'she', 'said.']`.

Comment: in this case I want the commas and punctuation still countable and not removed completely otherwise regex_split would be great and I will for sure use this in other projects since I didn't know it existed.

Comment: Sorry but the intention wasn't clear in the original question. I'm still not clear on your parsing algorithm, e.g. how would you parse "I want this but..., sorry can't say much."? However my main intention was to fix your indexing error, and not to suggest the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm new to posting here and wasn't that clear probably. You did indeed fix my indexing error but at the cost of making my algorithm not working properly. I simply want the parsing to separate punctuation from the words, other than just separating the words and remove unnecessary spaces. Like my original code did except that it got stuck on the last character which caused the original error. I will mark your comment as solved again since I think I can take it from here. I seem be too incomprehensible anyways.

Comment: If you want to stick to your own (unnecessarily complicated) algorithm, just fix the` while` conditions like I did to get rid of the indexing errors.

Comment: @Roslund I updated my answer to try to cover your need. I'm doing it in two passes as described.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I know it is not the simplest solution, even though I have not tried doing it in an other way (implementing packages). Appreciate the efforts!